# insert sqlalchemy's declarative dataclass

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The table is described as dataclass

```py
@registry.mapped_as_dataclass
class Instance:
    id: orm.Mapped[int] = orm.mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    column: orm.Mapped[str]

    __tablename__ = "test_table"
```

I'm trying to find a way to perform something obvious like

```py
instance = Instance(column="value")
await conn.execute(sa.insert(Instance).values(instance))
# or
await conn.execute(sa.insert(Instance), [instance])
```

But definitely doing something wrong because neither mypy nor sqlalchemy can agree with this code.

1. Mypy fails on instantiating with error `Unexpected keyword argument "column" for "Instance"`
2. SQLAlchemy fails to insert dataclass at all despite the fact it is sqlalchemy's dataclass

Do I miss something obvious or sqlalchemy's dataclasses are useful for table declaration only?

```
python 3.11.4
sqlalchemy 2.0.20
asyncpg 0.28.0
```